# Append BuildNumber to Newman report in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, postman, newman

I am trying to integrate my Postman scripts with Jenkins through Newman. In the build section in Jenkins, I am passing the Newman run command along with my collection.

**newman run collection.json --reporters html --reporter-html-export report.html**

How can I append build number, commit message(used during commit) and committer name(who committed) to the report generated using Newman? I am trying to run this job in Jenkins whenever a developer commits in the repo. I want the report name to be **report_buildnumber_commitmessage_committername.html**.

Comment: You can use environment variables of the [Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project). But having buildnumber as part of report name is fine, it is unique and single value will be allocated where as commitmessage and committername will be some times multiple items.

Comment: @Suresh thanks for your suggestion. So how can I generate unique report names? because everytime this job is run it's going to replace the existing reports. Appending build number will be a good option but along with the build numbers, I would like to add some more info to the report name which will help to understand easily what change has been done in the build by seeing the report name.

Comment: If you want to publish the generated reports from every build, you can check the HTML Publish Plugin it may suffix your requirement.